# Errors when converting object to date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert an object column in pandas to date time type, but get the following error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Using: Python 3

Type of pandas column that I am trying to convert: object

Format: "2017-12-19 17:03:21.655000+00:00"

The column also has Na values

[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0JQA.png)

```
basetable.reset_index(inplace=True, drop = True)
pd.to_datetime(basetable['session_start_time'], errors='coerce', format = '%Y-%m-%D %H:%M:%S')
```

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

**UPDATE**: If I convert all NA values into empty string, the conversion to_datetime works.

Comment: please give us sample data. the problem is on reset_index not on converting object to date time.

Comment: I have just added a pic for the sample data. Please check.

Comment: Also, the error is given when ruing pd.to_datetime(...), not when running reset_index()